# how to store image, video, audio file in aws server permanent outside tomcat deployed directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat

Currently, I am using AWS server as a beginner.

currently i am storing image, video file in project directory.

> tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/Video/

but whenever project is redeployed all uploaded file is remove because of project WAR file is replace.

but i don't want to store these inside of AWS root directory. I want to store these into outside project directory.

Comment: In your code give address of a mounted EBS volume , for more information you need to provide ur code.